# Subreport in ms-access displays values again and again

Tags: ms-access, subreport

I have a main report that contains two sub reports say rpt1 and rpt2.
rpt1 has a few records and rpt2 has calculation for those group of records.
Now,my problem is that rpt2 is getting displayed depending on number of records i have in rpt1.(For ex:if rpt 1 has 3 records then rpt2 is dispalyed 3 times with same data.

How do i ensure that rpt2 is displayed only once.

thanks!

Comment: Well do you want to show 3 records from `rpt1`?  If so, then how can the data from `rpt2` not be repeated?  What output do you want?

Comment: Can you move rpt2 out of the same design area as rpt1?

Comment: no i cannot move rpt2 out of the same design area as rpt1 as they must be displayed beside eachother-TDP

Comment: the calculation for rpt1 record should be displayed once once in rpt 2.example:if rpt1 has 3 records that sums up to 40 then rpt2 should display "40" only once.in my case it is getting displayed 3 times

Answer (score 0):

Can you move rpt2 into a Group Footer section, or perhaps the Report Footer?

[Guide to designing reports](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guide-to-designing-reports-876a6d27-59aa-467a-8240-ee6e01597291)